# android.jar different behavior in java and android

Tags: java, android

The method toString() in Class java.io.FileDescriptor has different behavior in the following two situation:

> When I code in an Android project using android.jar and run on a
>   virtual device. `new FileDescriptor.toString()` returns
>   "FileDescriptor[-1]".
>
> When I code in an plain Java project but use android.jar instead of
>   jdk library. It returns `java.io.FileDescriptor@8e3cf25`. It's the
>   address of new object.

I have read the implementation of toString in FileDescriptor.
In Android, it over writes the origin one to return the expected result. But in java, it didn't.
What make me confuse is why after replace jar file in java, I still can't get the result in Android.

Comment: The android.jar files from the Android SDK contains only dummies methods without code. Which "android.jar" do you refer to?

Comment: @Robert I used android.jar in sdk and source code from sdk/source.Do you mean it's different between the android.jar in sdk and that in virtual device?

Comment: Of course there is a difference. The android.jar from SDK contains only the API and method stubs. Nearly every method contains the code `throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");`

Comment: @Robert OK, I've made a huge misunderstanding of android.jar, thank you very much!

Comment: As Robert suggests, android.jar just contain stubs. The actual implementation is present only on android device containing the jar from manufacturer. You can possibly root an android device and pull out the actual jar and use a tool like JDGUI to walk through the actual code.